# Incorrect values written in stencil buffer

Tags: c++, opengl, stencil-buffer, picking

I am trying to pick objects on mouse click. For this I have followed [this tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Object_selection#Using_the_stencil_buffer_to_identify_objects), and tried to use the stencil buffer for this purpose.

Inside "game" loop I am trying to draw 10 (5 pairs) 'pick'able triangles as follows:

```
...

glClearColor(red, green, blue, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

glClearStencil(0); // this is the default value

/* Enable stencil operations */
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);

/*Some other drawing not involving stencil buffer*/

GLuint index = 1;
for (GLshort i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    //this returns 2 model matrices
    auto modelMatrices = trianglePairs[i].getModelMatrices(); 

    for (GLshort j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, index, -1);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelMatrices[j]));
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, BUFFER_OFFSET(2));
        index++;
    }
    /*Some other drawing not involving stencil buffer*/
}

/*Some other drawing not involving stencil buffer*/
...
```

However, when I am trying to read back the stencil values, I am getting wrong values. I am reading back the values as (this is also a [part of the above-mentioned tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Object_selection#Reading_back_information_from_the_framebuffer)):

```
GLuint index;
glReadPixels(xpos, Height - ypos - 1, 1, 1, GL_STENCIL_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &index);
```

Whenever, I click the first triangle of the pair I am getting values as `i+1`, whereas the correct value should have been `i`, and for the second triangle of the pair, I am getting `0` as `index`.

Please let me know what am I missing here?

**Update**
I have found that stencil values can be applied on quads. When I tried to apply the stencil value on unit square it worked correctly. However, when the quad is not unit square, it returns `0`. What is the reason for this?